# iOS XCode Storyboard controls moved and now look strange in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, simulator

I am following the course on iOS through iTunes university and working on the calculator project.  I moved the controls on the storyboard to make room for another control at the top.  Everything looks fine on the storyboard but when run in the simulator, controls are bunch up, on top of each other, and some are clearly off the top of the simulator screen.  This leads to the following very related questions.

1. How does one move controls around on the storyboard?  I went to the size inspector of each control (buttons in my case) and changed the 'Y' value (increased it by 10).  I did this for each control.  I didn't think about it as I was doing it because as I said, all looks fine on the storyboard. Is there a better way to move controls around?  I could not figure out how to grab more than one control at a time and move them.  Grabbing all and moving or all but one and moving would have been ideal.
2. I anticipate someone is going to say, "We need more info. " How do I show the storyboard?  Is there a xml file somewhere?  How is the storyboard saved?  How should I show the results of the simulator?
3. In general, what the heck is going on?  Why would things look so different in the simulator?
4. Is there a better forum/group to ask newbie questions about iOS programming?

My specs are these:
XCode 4.5.2
Ios simulator versions set to 6.0 and iPhone

Any other info needed?  Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: like dmaij said, you probably have set the interface builder for iphone 5 screen size and are using the simulator with a iphone 4 screen size. The only other reason why it would change would be if you were modifying the main view in your code somehow, a parent view will resize and reposition (depending on the settings) all of its subviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your simulated device size to 'freeform' instead of 'inferred'. This screen is a bit smaller so the controls are no longer overlapping. The latest xcode sets it by default to ios6 (screen size of iPhone 5)

**edit** For a better insight in xcode IDE, please refer to the documentation provided by apple (includes screenshots for clarity)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/000-About_Xcode/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215

Comment: dmaij,  That sounds promising.  Can you tell me where to find the simulated device size to switch it to freeform?  I don't see that option anywhere.  Also, currently on the simulator, the device is set to iPhone, and the version is set to iOS6 (both under Hardware menu).  On Xcode itself, all I see is near the run and stop button it says Calculator > iPhone 6.0 simulator. Is there anywhere else I should be checking for settings?

Comment: it's the pane located on the right side of the screen. Apple calls this the inspector pane, you can access it in the view menu | utilities and select one of those. When you select a view and look in the pace, the only looking like a shield holds the simulated size. The other ones are for color information, fonts etc, click through them to find out.

Comment: Thanks a bunch dmaij!  To those reading this later, let me note that I had to be sure I highlighted the entire dialog.  That is I picked outer frame of window.  Then as dmaij stated, one of the inspectors looks like a shield and says "simulated metrics".  Also, for reasons that are not clear to me, I first had to switch to Retina 3.5, adjust my dialog, run it, and then I was able to switch to "inferred".  Clearly I need to understand more.  I have the sinking feeling I should have been able to change the simulator itself, but that did not work.